# Prestashop config.xml files issue in sequential pattern

Tags: xml, prestashop-1.6

This is copy paste code of config.xml file of bankwire module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<module>
    <name>bankwire</name>
    <displayName><![CDATA[Bank wire]]></displayName>
    <version><![CDATA[0.7.2]]></version>
    <description><![CDATA[Accept payments for your products via bank wire transfer.]]></description>
    <author><![CDATA[PrestaShop]]></author>
    <tab><![CDATA[payments_gateways]]></tab>
    <confirmUninstall><![CDATA[Are you sure about removing these details?]]></confirmUninstall>
    <is_configurable>1</is_configurable>
    <need_instance>1</need_instance>
    <limited_countries></limited_countries>
</module>
```

It is auto genearated by Prestashop 1.6.0.9. And it gives these error as in attached screenshot.
[image: This is image of admin modules page of prestashop 1.6..0.9 where error display]

I have tried by deleting it. Also removed bankwire module. And problem will start now. If i disable/uninstall/delete the module then next blockadvertising module will show the same error. If i disable/uninstall/delete that module also it will be passed to next like blockbanner, blockbestseller and so on.

Let me also tell you that before and after it was working i didn't write a single line of code anywhere in the prestashop installation, nowhere. I am prestashop developer and developed more than 10 simple to ultra complex modules but this is weird. Please help me if you have solution for this issue.